# change default login information for sqlbuddy

Tags: php, sqlbuddy

I'm trying to edit login.php for sqlbuddy and not having any luck. I want to change the default host and user name that it prefills the login page with. I've tried changing these lines but the page doesn't change. :( Can someone give me a hint or 3?

```
$host = (isset($sbconfig['DefaultHost'])) ? $sbconfig['DefaultHost'] : "localhost";
$user = (isset($sbconfig['DefaultUser'])) ? $sbconfig['DefaultUser'] : "root";
$pass = (isset($sbconfig['DefaultPass'])) ? $sbconfig['DefaultPass'] : "";
```

full file:

```
<?php
/*

SQL Buddy - Web based MySQL administration
http://www.sqlbuddy.com/

login.php
- login to sql buddy

MIT license

2008 Calvin Lough <http://calv.in>

*/

include "functions.php";

$adapter = (isset($sbconfig['DefaultAdapter'])) ? $sbconfig['DefaultAdapter'] : "mysql";
$host = (isset($sbconfig['DefaultHost'])) ? $sbconfig['DefaultHost'] : "localhost";
$user = (isset($sbconfig['DefaultUser'])) ? $sbconfig['DefaultUser'] : "root";
$pass = (isset($sbconfig['DefaultPass'])) ? $sbconfig['DefaultPass'] : "";  

// SQLite only
$database = (isset($sbconfig['DefaultDatabase'])) ? $sbconfig['DefaultDatabase'] : "";  

if ($_POST) {
    if (isset($_POST['ADAPTER']))
        $adapter = $_POST['ADAPTER'];

    if (isset($_POST['HOST']))
        $host = $_POST['HOST'];

    if (isset($_POST['USER']))
        $user = $_POST['USER'];

    if (isset($_POST['PASS']))
        $pass = $_POST['PASS'];

    if (isset($_POST['DATABASE']))
        $database = $_POST['DATABASE'];
}

if (!in_array($adapter, $adapterList)) {
    $adapter = "mysql";
}

if (($adapter != "sqlite" && $host && $user && ($pass || $_POST)) || ($adapter == "sqlite" && $database)) {

    if ($adapter == "sqlite") {
        $connString = "sqlite:database=$database";
        $connCheck = new SQL($connString);
        $user = "";
        $pass = "";
    } else {
        $connString = "$adapter:host=$host";
        $connCheck = new SQL($connString, $user, $pass);
    }

    if ($connCheck->isConnected()) {
        $_SESSION['SB_LOGIN'] = true;
        $_SESSION['SB_LOGIN_STRING'] = $connString;
        $_SESSION['SB_LOGIN_USER'] = $user;
        $_SESSION['SB_LOGIN_PASS'] = $pass;

        $path = $_SERVER["SCRIPT_NAME"];
        $pathSplit = explode("/", $path);

        $redirect = "";

        for ($i=0; $i<count($pathSplit)-1; $i++) {
            if (trim($pathSplit[$i]) != "")
                $redirect .= "/" . $pathSplit[$i];
        }

        if (array_key_exists("HTTPS", $_SERVER) && $_SERVER['HTTPS'] == "on") {
            $protocol = "https://";
        } else {
            $protocol = "http://";
        }

        $redirect = $protocol . $_SERVER["HTTP_HOST"] . $redirect . "/";

        redirect($redirect);
        exit;
    } else {
        $error = __("There was a problem logging you in.");
    }
}

startOutput();

?><!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN"
"http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html40/strict.dtd">

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" version="-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.1//EN" xml:lang="en">
    <head>
        <title>SQL Buddy</title>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8"/>
        <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="<?php echo smartCaching("css/common.css"); ?>" />
        <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="<?php echo smartCaching("css/navigation.css"); ?>" />
        <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="<?php echo smartCaching("css/print.css"); ?>" media="print" />
        <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="<?php echo themeFile("css/main.css"); ?>" />
        <!--[if lte IE 7]>
            <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="<?php echo themeFile("css/ie.css"); ?>" />
        <![endif]-->
        <script type="text/javascript" src="<?php echo smartCaching("js/mootools-1.2-core.js"); ?>"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="<?php echo smartCaching("js/helpers.js"); ?>"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="<?php echo smartCaching("js/movement.js"); ?>"></script>
    </head>
    <body style="background: none">
    <div id="container">
    <div id="loginform">
        <form name="loginform" method="post">
        <div class="loginspacer">
        <?php

        // make sure they aren't using IE below version 7

        $ua = $_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'];

        $ie = strstr($ua, 'MSIE') ? true : false;
        $ieVer = $ie ? preg_split('/msie/i', $ua) : false;
        $ieVer = $ieVer ? floatval($ieVer[1]) : false;

        // turn into whole number
        $ieVer = (int)($ieVer);

        if ($ua && $ie && $ieVer < 7) {

            ?>
            <table cellpadding="0" id="tb">
            <tr>
            <td class="loginheader"><h3><?php echo __("Unsupported browser"); ?></h3><a href="http://www.sqlbuddy.com/help/" title="Help"><?php echo __("Help!"); ?></a></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
            <td><?php echo __("We're sorry, but currently only Internet Explorer 7 is supported. It is available as a free download on Microsoft's website. Other free browsers are also supported, including Firefox, Safari, and Opera."); ?></td>
            </tr>
            </table>
            <?php

        } else {

            ?>
            <table cellpadding="0" id="tb">
            <tr>
            <td colspan="2"><div class="loginheader"><h3><strong><?php echo __("Login"); ?></strong></h3><a href="http://www.sqlbuddy.com/help/" title="Help"><?php echo __("Help!"); ?></a></div></td>
            </tr>
            <?php
            if (isset($error)) {
                echo '<tr><td colspan="2"><div class="errormess">' . $error . '</div></td></tr>';
            }
            if (isset($_GET['timeout'])) {
                echo '<tr><td colspan="2"><div class="errormess">' . __("Your session has timed out. Please login again.") . '</div></td></tr>';
            }

            if (sizeof($adapterList) > 1) {

            ?>
            <tr>
            <td class="field"></td>
            <td>
            <select name="ADAPTER" id="ADAPTER" onchange="adapterChange()">
            <?php

            if (in_array("mysql", $adapterList)) {
                ?>
                <option value="mysql"<?php if ($adapter == "mysql") echo " selected"; ?>><?php echo __("MySQL"); ?></option>
                <?php
            }

            if (in_array("sqlite", $adapterList)) {
                ?>
                <option value="sqlite"<?php if ($adapter == "sqlite") echo " selected"; ?>><?php echo __("SQLite"); ?></option>
                <?php
            }

            ?>
            </select>
            </td>
            </tr>
            <?php

            }

            ?>
            </table>
            <table cellpadding="0" id="REGOPTIONS"<?php if ($adapter == "sqlite") echo ' style="display: none"'; ?>>
            <tr>
            <td class="field"><?php echo __("Host"); ?>:</td>
            <td><input type="text" class="text" name="HOST" value="<?php echo $host; ?>" /></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
            <td class="field"><?php echo __("Username"); ?>:</td>
            <td><input type="text" class="text" name="USER" value="<?php echo $user; ?>" /></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
            <td class="field"><?php echo __("Password"); ?>:</td>
            <td><input type="password" class="text" name="PASS" id="PASS" /></td>
            </tr>
            </table>
            <table cellpadding="0" id="LITEOPTIONS"<?php if ($adapter == "mysql") echo ' style="display: none"'; ?>>
            <tr>
            <td class="field"><?php echo __("Database"); ?>:</td>
            <td><input type="text" class="text" name="DATABASE" id="DATABASE" value="<?php echo $database; ?>" /></td>
            </tr>
            </table>
            <table cellpadding="0">
            <tr>
            <td class="field"></td>
            <td><input type="submit" class="inputbutton" value="<?php echo __("Submit"); ?>" /></td>
            </tr>
            </table>
            <?php

        }

        ?>
        </div>
        </form>
    </div>
    </div>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    <!--

    <?php

    if ($adapter != "sqlite") {
        echo "$('PASS').focus();";
    } else {
        echo "$('DATABASE').focus();";
    }

    ?>

    if (!navigator.cookieEnabled) {
        var tb = $('tb');
        var newTr = new Element('tr');
        var newTd = new Element('td');
        newTd.setAttribute("colspan", 2);
        var newDiv = new Element('div');
        newDiv.className = "errormess";
        newDiv.set('text', "<?php echo __("You don't appear to have cookies enabled. For sessions to work, most php installations require cookies."); ?>");
        newTd.appendChild(newDiv);
        newTr.appendChild(newTd);
        tb.appendChild(newTr);
    }

    function adapterChange() {
        var adapter = $('ADAPTER');
        var currentAdapter = adapter.options[adapter.selectedIndex].value;

        if (currentAdapter == "sqlite") {
            $('REGOPTIONS').style.display = 'none';
            $('LITEOPTIONS').style.display = '';
            $('DATABASE').focus();
        } else {
            $('REGOPTIONS').style.display = '';
            $('LITEOPTIONS').style.display = 'none';
            $('PASS').focus();
        }

    }

    // -->
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried changing the config array?

$sbconfig['DefaultHost']

if that exists then it will use that (im guessing you know how ternary statements work? there just simple IF/ELSE statements)

Edit:

Inside config.php you will see near the top of the file

```
$sbconfig['DefaultHost'] = "localhost";
$sbconfig['DefaultUser'] = "root";
```

Change those values. Thats should work for you

Comment: I'm not terribly familiar, no. I changed the word localhost to server.domain.lan and the user root to admin..... those are the 2 items I'd like to change; but not having luck. Is that the right place to change them?